# plot multiple days data 24 hour in am/pm format but keep getting irregular xticks

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

my final dataframe which i used for plotting

[image]

I have a dataframe with index as DateTime and temperature as values. Want to plot weekly and monthly data with time on x-axis and temperature on y-axis. By weekly data I mean to plot 7 days data in one 24 hour x axis graph so that I can see if some pattern occurs.

My original dataframe looks like this:

```
Date                      Temperature
2017-04-05 11:18:00-04:00  32.716833
2017-04-05 11:19:00-04:00  32.635500
2017-04-05 11:20:00-04:00  32.547333
...                              ...
2017-07-20 20:37:00-04:00  35.219667
2017-07-20 20:38:00-04:00  35.240000
2017-07-20 20:39:00-04:00  35.233000
```

Here is my code. I am trying to plot temperature, moving average for 7 days.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jugz.png)

```
#Weekly with matplotlib sorting dates in correct order
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import time
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
i = 0
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,8))#figsize=(15,15)
markers=['o', '.', ',', 'x', '+', 'v', '^', '<', '>', 's', 'd']
i=0   # variable using for counter if i==7 (weekly)
#made a list of unique dates for loop  
for date in dates:
    # selecting dataframe for specific date
    df = df_sub[df_sub.date == date]
    plt.plot(df['NewTime'],df['TEMP'],markers[i],label=date)   
    i=i+1   
    if i % 1==0:
        i = 0
        print(date)
        plt.plot(df['NewTime'],df['fifteenminavg'], label='Mean', linestyle='--',c='darkgrey')
#         plt.xticks( rotation=25 )
#         ax=plt.gca()
        ax.set_xlim(["00:00:00", "23:59:59"])
        plt.title("Skin Temperature (Week="+str(date)+")",fontsize=20)
#         ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 24, endpoint=True))
#         ticks = ['12 AM', '1 AM', '2 AM', '3 AM', '4 AM', '5 AM', '6 AM', '7 AM','8 AM','9 AM','10 AM','11 AM','12 PM', '1 PM', '2 PM', '3 PM', '4 PM',  '5 PM', '6 PM', '7 PM', '8 PM', '9 PM', '10 PM', '11 PM' ]
#         ax.set_xticklabels(tickstime)
#         ax=plt.gca()
#         hours = mdates.HourLocator(interval = 1)
#         h_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
#         ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
#         ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(h_fmt) 
        ax.set_ylabel('Temperature (°C)')
        ax.set_xlabel('Time')
        fig.autofmt_xdate()
        plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
        fig.tight_layout()
        plt.show()  
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,8))#figsize=(15,15)
```

Here is my output graph.. you can see the x-ticks are not having regular intervals.

I want them to be like 12 am, 6am, 12pm, 6pm, 12am

The plot with x-axis issue of time

[image]

Comment: Use the hour locator like you have commented out.

Comment: I have tried that. It didn't work. Hour locator work if I am plotting data for a single day or multiple days but with all dates on x axis like monday, to sunday.